# Assign users to specific user group on registration

Tags: php, joomla

I'm using joomla, I wan't to assign a user to a specific user group on registration.

Here's what I have done so far:
Edited the default.php in template/html/com_users/registration/ adding the following code.

```
<?php endforeach;?>
 <dt>
     I am a:
 </dt>
 <dd>
     <select name="cb_regusergroup"> 
         <option value="student">Student</option>
         <option value="business">Business</option> 
     </select>
 </dd>
 <?php 
    $value = JRequest::getVar('cb_regusergroup', '');
    if($value=="student"){
       $groups = '10'; 
    }elseif($value=="business"){
       $groups = '11'; 
    }
```

?>

I'm not really sure where to go from here.  When I register all users get added to the public user group which is default.  10 and 11 are the user group id's.  Can someone give me some advice on where to go from here.

Comment: what version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: I'm using Joomla 3.1.1

Comment: Right, you will need to edit more than just the *default.php*. This file is simply used for the view. Have a read of [this](http://www.pages-and-items.com/extensions/frontend-user-access/faqs/assign-users-to-group-from-select-on-registration-form). Also, don't use `JRequest` as this has been deprecated. You should use `JInput`. More information on this can be found [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput)

Answer (score 0):

you have to follow this tutorial

http://www.pages-and-items.com/extensions/frontend-user-access/faqs/assign-users-to-group-from-select-on-registration-form

Comment: Thanks for your reply this is the tutorial I have been using.  At the end of this tutorial is says:

To save the group selection when the user submits the form:
1. Go to the FUA configuration > tab 'users'.
2. Select at 'assign to group from select on registration form' the checkbox 'enable'.
3. Paste this code in the second textarea:

Where can I find the FUA configuration in Joomla?